# Is there any way to store single.php wordpress file into a php variable

Tags: theme-development

I am finding an way to store single.php file in a variable in wordpress file, I want to use preg_match_all to this file.

```html
$regex = "~(<h([2-6]))(.*?>(.*)<\/h[2-6]>)~";
$singlefile= single.php

preg_match_all($regex, $singlefile, $heading_results);
```

Can anyone tell me proper way to do this?

Comment: Try `ob_start();
include "single.php";
$singlefile = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Given that this is a question regarding PHP rather than WordPress, it may be considered off-topic for our Stack. That said, Anoop's suggestion will execute the `single.php` file within the current environment and store any output in the variable. To get the actual contents of the file in a variable, use PHP's [filesystem functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as you would with any other file.